# Do I need to manually restore the health of the dwellers everytime?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I have noticed that the health of the dwellers keeps decreasing, but very slowly. I sometimes restore their health manually, using Stimpacks and RadAways, but I have also sometimes noticed that all the dweller's health would restore automatically (its reset to 100%).

Am I missing something here?

Is there a particular time where all dwellers will automatically have their health and radiation levels reset, or Should I continue to generate Stimpacks and RadAways to manually restore their health and radiation?

Comment: You should behave your dwellers better, the normal is that they heal over time, not get damage over time. Be sure you have enough supplies for them!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dwellers automatically restore their Health and remove Radiation slowly when they are in the vault.

But there are some Exceptions:

- On level up health is automatically restored to 100%
- They only restore health when enough food is available.
- they only remove radiation when enough water is available.
- If you revive a dead dweller health is 100% and radition is eliminated.
- as far as i know, they recover only when you have the game open, when you have game closed they do not restore health or remove radiation, or at least a lot slower...

I have sometimes a bug that one dweller, which came radiated from deserted, not reduced radiation when in dwault, in that case I had to use radaway. But this bug occured only in rare cases and not for all dwellers.

Answer (score 0):

I have found something similar with two major causes directly responsible for the declines.  First, I tend to have fairly constant attacks by raiders/deathclaws.  All my top level dwellers are heavily armored, weaponized and skilled to eliminate threats quickly, but it still takes a toll.  Secondly, which is actually more common for my style of play, my food stores are not always very far above the minimum and the dwellers "starve" a little bit.  The less food that is stored, closer too or below the minimums, the faster they starve and become hurt.

Like @kl78 said, the restoration can occur manually, if you have a plethora of stimpaks.  Restoration occurs automatically as each dweller levels and there is plenty of food stored.  Finally, they will heal as time passes with food available.  Max out your food stores to help speed it up!

Comment: fires raiders and infestations all cause health to drop best solution I have found is to just check in once a day or so